# Python pandas subtotal for dynamic grouping, how to get the total to always appear end of a grouping?

Tags: python, pandas

I've managed to get close, as I'm able to get the total to correctly sum up each individual group, my issue is with getting the total to appear at the end of each group, below is my working -
(I'm using Django, so I'm using a queryset as data )

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(
        get_daily_transaction_object(value, SQLLIST, date).values('posgroupid',
                                                                  'posid',
                                                                  'cardscheme',
                                                                  'transactionamount',
                                                                  'transactiontype',
                                                                  'currencycode')))
        def f(x):
        a = x['transactionamount'].nunique()
        b = x[df['transactiontype'] == 1]['transactionamount'].sum()
        c = x[df['transactiontype'] == 4]['transactionamount'].sum()
        d = x[df['transactiontype'] == 3]['transactionamount'].sum()
        e = x['transactionamount'].sum()

        return pd.Series([a, b, c, d, e], index=['transactions', 'sales', 'refund', 'cashback', 'Total'])

    grouped_df = df.groupby(['currencycode',
                             'posgroupid',
                             'posid',
                             'cardscheme']).apply(f)

    subtotal = grouped_df.sum(level=[0, 1, 2]).assign(cardscheme='Total').set_index('cardscheme', append=True)

    grouped_new = pd.concat([grouped_df, subtotal]).sort_index()

    context = {'desc': 'Transaction Report',
               'report': grouped_new.to_html(classes='white_space_df')
               }
```

the above calculates correctly but places the total in seemingly random places, this is causing an issue when I have dynamically sized data.

Is there a way to always have the total appear at the end of a group?
picture for refenrece.
[image: python pandas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you are setting Total as an instance of cardscheme so as to group it under the column of cardscheme.  Then you set cardscheme as an index and finally you sorted the index.  Hence, Total is sorted (as index) together with other cardscheme e.g. Visa, MasterCard in alphabetic order.

How about you sort other cardscheme items first (by sorting index), then add Total without further sorting the index ?  Just an example (not fully tested), change the codes sequence to:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['currencycode',
                             'posgroupid',
                             'posid',
                             'cardscheme']).apply(f)

# add the following to set index and sort the index before concat Total
sorted_grouped_df = grouped_df.set_index('cardscheme').sort_index()


subtotal = grouped_df.sum(level=[0, 1, 2]).assign(cardscheme='Total').set_index('cardscheme', append=True)

# revise to concat the sorted_grouped_df with subtotal AND remove sort index
grouped_new = pd.concat([sorted_grouped_df, subtotal])
```

Comment: Hey, I think you got it mate - although your example didn't work, you set me on the right path, the alphabetical part was the last puzzle piece, I've just changed "total" to "| total |", bit of a cheese I know, but it'll work every time